# Add image or file to Cart using code Magento

Tags: php, magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magento attach a file to order or product in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942721/magento-attach-a-file-to-order-or-product-in-cart)

How to do I add image to Cart
The image will be on the host sever.
I know this can be done through custom option on the product page.
Is it possible to add it through Querystring.

```
require_once \'app/Mage.php\';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton(\'core/session\', array(\'name\'=>\'frontend\'));

$cart = Mage::getSingleton(\'checkout/cart\');
cart->addProduct(108, array(\'qty\' => 1,\'super_attribute\'=>array(\'502\'=>\'46\')));

$cart->save();
$cart_count = $cart->getItemsCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you want to be able to add a product to the cart with an option:

`http://your.site.com/checkout/cart/add/product/29/?super_attribute[502]=46&qty;=1`

Reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring

Comment: I would like to attach a image or a file to the http://magentoserver.com/checkout/cart/add?product=13&qty=1&options[12]=image.jpg

Comment: Attaching the physical image from the URI would require some custom code to allow for such, out of box the functionality (that I'm aware of) doesn't exist.